# video tag not playing a video/webm file in Safari

Tags: html, video, safari

I have tried the solutions outlined here:
[HTML5 videos not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832452/html5-videos-not-working-in-safari) 
[Video tag not working in Safari now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982252/video-tag-not-working-in-safari-now)

without any success.

Here is what I have:

`<video controls class="video" autoplay loop poster="video/Innocence.jpg" data-setup="{}">
          <source src="video/main-vid.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>`

Plays in Chrome and FF, but not Safari. So my iPhone does not play it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does the video not play _at all_ (even when using the controls), or does it just not autoplay?

Comment: Does not play at all.

Comment: Check out my answer below. Safari does not support WebM, so you'll need to provide additional formats.

Answer (score 3):

WebM video format does not appear to be currently supported by Safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=webm

To reach the widest audience, you'll want to use MP4, Ogg, and WebM formats:

```
<video controls class="video" autoplay loop poster="video/Innocence.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="video/main-vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video/main-vid.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="video/main-vid.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Note that the MP4 source should be listed first to work in older versions of iOS.

Comment: It is supported now, but there are other problems.

Comment: I have the same issue, I cant play mp4 video in Safari, so do I need to convert blob after we record the video the format you mentioned `mp4, ogg, webm` because after I record video I am saving in aws s3 as mp4 extension. Due to this Safari is not playing ??