# WebApi Serving Videos on Mobile Devices

Tags: ios, html5-video, mobile-safari, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using WebApi to serve videos on a website. I've tested this on all major desktop browsers and the HTML5 Video tag plays the video as expected. However, I can't get this to work on iPhones (Mobile Safari). The Get() method is never called even after pressing the play button.

**WEBAPI CODE**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{

    var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/testbw2.mp4");

    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

    if (Request.Headers.Range != null)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage partialResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
            partialResponse.Content = new ByteRangeStreamContent(stream, Request.Headers.Range, _mediaType);
            return partialResponse;
        }
        catch (InvalidByteRangeException invalidByteRangeException)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(invalidByteRangeException);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        HttpResponseMessage fullResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        fullResponse.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        fullResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = _mediaType;
        return fullResponse;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<video controls>
    <source src="http://localhost/WebApplication24/api/range" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

If I change the video src to point directly to the file...

`src="http://localhost/WebApplication24/Content/testbw2.mp4"`

It works so I know this isn't an encoding issue.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I get the feeling mobile safari wont request the video src if the url doesn't end with .mp4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the possible reasons *(some)* that your file does not work and possible solutions:

1. Safari is fully expecting an actually-named MP4. No other combinations of file and mime-type works. The other browsers opt for the WEBM file first, especially Chrome. *[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093031/1155650)*
2. On iOS prior to 7.0.2, Safari does support HTML5 Video, the Quicktime Player has to be installed in order for this to work. *[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21255499/1155650)*
3. Also there are issues in which steaming doesn't work in iOS 7 where as local files does. *[source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5379998)*
4. For some reason videos would not play on iOS unless `controls="true"` is set. *[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25670764/1155650)*
5. iOS doesn't support all the profiles that h.264 provides. You have to encode your h264 with a baseline profile only in order for it to be playable on iphone/ipad. [Encoding with Miro Video Converter](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#miro) might help. *[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269704/1155650)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer it turned out to be number one. I now have to append all my service calls with .mp4 even though its not returning a static file grrrr

Comment: Any idea why safari does this? Other browsers use the type attribute and content-type header.

Comment: Because it's ios and they believe whatever they do is right. *No questions asked*. I haven't seen a work around for this yet. If I find I will update my answer.